# Is the log file becomes deleted, if I change the backup type?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, transaction-log

I need to backup the transaction log file of the database but backup type of it is "simple". I will change it as "full" but I cannot be sure about log file will be deleted or not after this operation.

Can anyone help me at this point? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to change the recovery model from Simple to Full.
You can read more about hte differences here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx

Right now you are using the simple recovery model. Your log file is probably empty because the transaction are deleted as soon as the real data are written to disk.

If you switch to full, you won't loose any data. 
Once it is done, it will keep the transaction in the log file and it will grow until you back it up (LOG backup), shrink it (avoid that), switch back to Simple or you file or disk gets full.

If you switch from Full to Simple, you will loose the transaction in the LOG file but you won't loose any data.